# Steam pudding in square bowl

Tags: pudding, steamed-pudding

Emergency steam pudding q.

Is there a reason I couldn't use a square dish to steam a pudding in the oven (St John's steamed lemon pudding specifically)? Like, is the round bowl shape a structural necessity?

Sorry if this sounds daft. I can't find info anywhere.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the square dish. If the opening is smaller than the base inside the bowl (unlikely) then you will not be able to get it out in one piece. In any case you should be extra careful when removing it from the dish as the corners will be more vulnerable to crumbling.

Comment: You might want to butter the dish even if you normally wouldn't, especially in the corners